# C Programming Language Exercise 1.5.4 (editing error found in code?)

Tags: c

I'm continue working with the Classic K&R Book "The C Programming Language", Second Edition.

## SCENE.

I was having problems with the output of exercise in page 22 about word counting. Not getting the desired output.

## QUESTION.

Finally I think that found a mistake in the code syntax ?

## CODE FRON ORIGINAL PDF.

Exercise say (Copy and paste from PDF):

> 1.5.4 Word Counting The fourth in our series of useful programs counts lines, words, and characters, with the loose definition that a word is
>   any sequence of characters that does not contain a blank, tab or
>   newline. This is a bare-bones version of the UNIX program wc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1 /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0 /* outside a word */

/* count lines, words, and characters in input */
main()
{
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

    state = OUT;
    nl = nw = nc = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
           state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT) {
           state = IN;
           ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

## CHANGE NEDED TO WORK

Where Say:

```
if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
```

No need to say?

```
if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
```

Please.

If my assessment is correct. The same error appears later on page 23 which explains the line.

## CONFIRMATION NEEDED.

It tells me exactly what the logic but it seems so incredible that this error is in a book like this. I need a confirmation, there will be this freaking.

Thank soo much in advance for your comments.

## ADDED AT USER Rohan REQUEST:

What's difference in 2 lines? Make question more clear. –  Rohan 33 mins ago.

## ANSWER to Rohan:

Hello and Thanks to question. In C

> x = 5 is used to assign to the variable x the value 5, for example.

However, if what you want is to check the equality symbol is correct ==

> if x == 5 Say if x is equal to 5 ...

As you can see the book are assigning c = '\t'

which makes no sense and was giving me errors

"If c is equal to tab" is `if (c == '\t')` Where \t are the TAB key.

I hope I have clarified some doubt

And thanks for asking

You can check http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm

Where you can see:

> == Checks if the values of two operands are equal or not, if yes then condition becomes true.
>
> (A == B) is not true.

Comment: What's difference in 2 lines? Make question more clear.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct, errare humanum est ;)

Comment: finally decided to sit down and go through k&r, and I was bewildered that this error, so early, made it into the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in your assessment that the `=` needs to be replaced with a `==`.

Typos happen, even in books and even in K&R.

However, you mention that you copied the code straight from a PDF. That PDF was likely OCRed from a book and OCR software is far from perfect, so mistakes can do happen.

Comment: Won, Thanks for your fast reply, I have the paper book from ebay and have the same mistake. I check it and look for a PDF in Google to paste the code here to skip any input errors (by me).

Comment: NP. Yeah, like I said, stuff like this does happen in actual print books and I've seen PDFs that are full of errors so I you need to be on your toes all the time.

Comment: I understand that there are errors like this in books of other things, but in a book like this programming error that type you can go crazy, apart from a huge lack of respect for two people I admire as K & R. Too bad the reviewers of the publisher.